# How to adjust paths/privileges to files (log, sqlite database) tomcat application uses?

Tags: java, tomcat6

**Edit:** I rewrited the question to include newest findings and remove already fixed issues.

I'm developing servlet application `myapp` previously created by my colleagues.
I develop and run it under Debian, Tomcat servers I use are version 6.

In this application there are three files used:

```
myapp-database.db - sqlite file, if is is not present application creates it
myapp-log.xml - log file, it is opened/created by the application
myapp-config.xml - configuration files, included in /usr/main/resources
```

If I run this on Eclipse-inner-Tomcat installed in my home directory,
files: `myapp-database.db` and `myapp-log.xml` are created directly in my home directory.

There is problem with this files when if I deploy the application to system Tomcat, installed with aptitude.
It shows in `catalina.out`:

```
Error while initialising logger: mylog.xml
java.io.IOException: Couldn't get lock for mylog.xml

...

SEVERE: couldn't initialize database:
    opening db: 'mydb.db': Permission denied

java.sql.SQLException: opening db: 'mydb.db': Permission denied

...
```

I deploy the application like that:

```
sudo cp myapp.war /var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/
```

Then I'm not able to turn system Tomcat on. If I remove the app from `webapps` it is ok.

I made somewhere on disc the directory and changed owner to tomcat.
I changed the filenames in code to absolute paths so that they will be created in the directory.
Tomcat turned on and didn't crash, the files were created there.

Is this the normal way of dealing with this issue?
Creating the application files totally outside the tomcat?
I think this makes application less portable/harder to install.

Maybe I should put the files in `/usr/main/resources` like the `myapp-config.xml` which works ok?
But I'm not really sure how to make paths point to them then?
I also don't like this solution because the application is supposed to create the files if they don't exists.

Comment: It seems to be a file system permission issue

Comment: I know, but what is the standard way of dealing with it? How do you adjust the filepaths when deploying application to Tomcat? Do you just create them somewhere on disc (doesn't this cause the WAR to be not portable?)? What user should the files belong to?

Comment: I suggest to try to install an instance of tomcat on user folder and, start tomcat with sudo iff you need to use the port 80

Comment: Is this really the way people deal with this issue? I already created one tomcat for _developer_ purposes (with eclipse). I want to have separate _production_ tomcat do deploy the application when it's done. I also don't think you should start tomcat with superuser privileges (I think something different from the case for `sudo start service tomcat6`).

Comment: It seems there actually is problem with tomcat6 itself. Is shows `ok` on startup but it is not running afterwards. And I thought it over and it probably wouldn't get broken just because of application exceptions. But I'm sure there is a way to use _system_ tomcat, what for would it be then?

Comment: I usually don't use the system tomcat. I download a new one and define an environment folder with all component needed (webserver, document management, etc). I start tomcat with sudo privilege to run on port 80.